# Some of LEDs connected in series remain on

Tags: led, pcb-design, led-driver, leakage-current

I know that even tiny leakage currents can make an LED glow weakly and there are many answers to similar questions, but my problem is different.

I have 6 power LEDs connected in series and they are driven by an AL8860, which is basically a current regulator that uses a low side switch. When I apply a low voltage to the driver‘a control pin the LED current is supposed to be off. But actually some (not all) LEDs remain dimmed while the others are completely off.

How can that be? Even if the driver leaks some current, how would that only affect some LEDs?
As they are connected in series I would have expected them all to be in the same state.
The only explanation I have is that there are further leaks on the pcb, but that‘s hard to imagine, because there are almost no voltage drops on the pcb. The LEDs are assembled on an aluminum pcb (1oz, 0.3mm spacing).

Are there any tricks to force the LEDs off, beside shorting them (which is common practice with laser diodes)?

Comment: With very low currents not every LED's visibility will be the same. So there's no conflict. Apparently, your AL8860 isn't all that great (or you are using it wrong, I suppose.) But you could apply a resistor across all of your series LEDs. What's the nominal current when ON and what's the high side rail voltage for your 6 power LED series chain?

Comment: @jonk I‘m curious why the AL8860 is not so great. I‘ve allready tried to put a resistor (10k) across the led chain, but that didn’t have any effect. The nominal high current is 750mA while I use both PWM and analog dimming (my ctrl signal is a modulation of an analog level). My rail is at 24V.

Comment: @jonk what could I possibly doing wrong with the driver? I didn‘t expect it to be very complicated as the circuit consists of only few components and I stuck to the layout recommendations in the DS.

Comment: I have never used the AL8860. I'm just depending on your own assurances and observations for that comment. Usually, a low-side driver will use a quality current mirror design where each output actually has a separate way of turning them off (more circuitry required.) However, if they are using a very simple current mirror arrangement and a poor method of disabling the output, all that happens is it still has enough gate/base-emitter drive to allow a low current. And that would be a design problem in my mind. Try adding a \$33\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor across your LED chain. Let me know.

Comment: @jonk Well, I used the AL8860 before and don‘t remember to have had the problem of not being able turn the LEDs off. So I‘ll have to figure out what is different now. Actually my question was just about some LEDs remaining dimmed while the others appear to be off completely. You say, that has something to do with the LEDs‘ behavior at low currents? Because from my understanding whenever an electron passes the pn junction there is a chance that it emits a photon and I didn‘t expect this probability to deviate between individuals (variations in forward voltage should not have an effect here).

Comment: Well, I don't see a circuit of what you used before and what you are now using. Is there a difference between the cases? If so, let's isolate the discussion to those differences and what may be affecting the results. Was the 24 V different before, for example? Etc. Regarding LEDs at low current, things start to get near the thermal generation of hole-pairs at the junction. Usually, in LEDs, this junction has a lot of surface area. The effects are statistical and impacted by impurities and differences in doping between devices. So this becomes more important at low currents.

Comment: But you should also have a solid, good turn-off by the IC. That's a different issue and needs to be resolved.

Comment: @jonk I really appreciate your enthusiasm, but this question is not why the driver does not turn off, but only why **specific** LEDs remain on. So you say, this is typical for LEDs operates at low currents, it’s not caused by leakage currents on the aluminum pcb? I‘ll dive into the driver problem on my own first and eventually I‘ll come back with another question concerning this problem (including all the information, of course).

Comment: @jonk “But you should also have a solid, good turn-off by the IC“ - I absolutely agree and I‘m going to do troubleshooting! From the evaluation boards I have I can say that the al8860 definitely shuts down current sufficiently when CTRL is below 290mV, which is intended behavior. So the problem lies in my circuit, not the IC.

Comment: I'm sure if you measured the current you'd find that it is a measurable, non-zero value and that you'd get the same measurement no matter where you inserted the ammeter. If are thinking that there is any difference in current, one to another, then the only way that happens is if you have some kind of serious leakage taking place. And I just don't believe you would miss such a problem. So the issue of LED brightness variations must be due to thermal hole-pair creation, impurities, and dopant variations in the devices compared to the low remaining current when "off." Nothing else makes sense.

Comment: It's possible that the device cannot stand off 24 V. I don't know what you were using before as a rail. But Diodes Inc is a good company, now that I look to see who makes them. It looks like a switcher, though. So.... I think you'll find the problem there. Have you checked all of your node voltages with a scope? (Including that 0.2 CTRL node voltage?) By the way, CTRL looks a little funky to me. They seem to let it use an analog voltage to control the current and/also allow open collector/drain PWM. So there may be something tricky going on inside.